# Can PHP cancel an error notice in a PHP file, not in php.ini?

Tags: php

As I know, we can set

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR
display_errors = Off
```

in php.ini, for a globe setting.

But I only want to cancel an errors notice in one PHP file, not all the pages.  when something will print in the page like:

`Warning: getimagesize(CU1402715579480Bv-300x286--50x50.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported...`

Can we close an errors notice on the page, like `<php set_time_limit(0); ?>` or `<php date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see

- [`error_reporting()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to suppress the error
- [`error_get_last()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) to get the error message afterwards if necessary

Related: The [error handling functions chapter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php) in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, see example:

```
if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
}
```

Please read:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Just a note, this will set it during the script execution, not globally.

Answer (score 2):

Besides setting `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` in the script, you can also individually suppress errors for specific functions using the shut up operator:

```
 @getimagesize("http://wrong.wrong.wrg/nonexist.png");
```

Though in your case you might want to set `protocol_version` by requesting the file separataly with http context options, http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php - this would eliminate the actual error. (Or as lazy alternative use a HTTP class/library.)

Comment: Agreed - for individual commands, the dreaded `@` is equivalent to turning error reporting off and on again explicitly, and much less code. (In this case, the OP seems to be requiring it for a whole file, though.)

Comment: @Pekka: I was assuming it's really just about the non-critical image probing (which probably threw a second error from getimagesize itself). Not sure what the timezone question part is about. So there might be more errors. But if he wanted to be extra-lazy `@include("imagescript.php");` would do the trick ;}

Answer (score 0):

In your specific script, which generate the notice, you can put this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

All the error (E_ALL) except notices (E_NOTICE) will be shown.

Aka.

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(E_ALL ~E_NOTICE);
maybe a syntax error over here i'm not pretty sure though